# Using a table from another database

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

When using EF core 6, I'd like to mark one table as coming from another database in SQL Server. It looks like the annotation allows specifying the schema, so I can do:

```
[Table("PRODUCTS", Schema = "dbo")]
```

But how I need to go one level lower. Unfortunately this:

```
[Table("PRODUCTS", Schema = "Drugs.dbo")]
```

results in `[Drugs.dbo].[PRODUCTS]` in the query, so I can't work around it that way.

How can I specify the database for that model without a separate database connection? I need to use tables from 2 catalogs in a single query. (Without any database-side changes)

Comment: @DaleK Correct it's in another database/catalog.

Comment: I don't think the term `catalog` is a common way of referring to a database... it might make more sense to people to change it.

Comment: @DaleK Changed. MS seems to use both (see `InitialCatalog` in connection string). I'm happy either way.

Comment: There's a terrible hack which actually works at https://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2020/november/accessing-multiple-databases-from-the-same-dbcontext-in-ef-core/ Unless someone comes up with a better answer, I'll summarise that post.

Comment: You can use this [extension](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore), readme has sample of usage of `DatabaseName` function.